# Could documentation (beta) site be used for other concepts?

Tags: discussion, documentation

Could documentation (beta) site be used for other concepts?

For example, a board games rule site.

It would allow users to create a set of rules that match and improves upon the original rules for a board game.

I know that some board games have not explained things well to me in the past. The ability for me to come to a site (like Documentation beta on stack overflow). Read the community curated rules for a board game, with context, images, discussion on why this rule works the way it does, approvals of rule changes.

Also even a sub section for users to create add on rule sets or whole new rule sets for a board game.

I had this idea a while ago, but do not have the time to do it myself (originally thought wiki style components w/markdown text). I really think it would fit the style here.

Any plans on allowing other styles than just Documentation to be used for that type of site (Documentation beta on SO)?

Comment: Sounds like you just want a wiki.  There are lots of readily available wiki platforms out there for you to use.

Comment: There are plans (in the future) to perhaps roll out Documentation to other sites in the Stack Exchange network. As far as I know, none of them would be amenable to this type of use.

Comment: Related/Cross-site duplicate: [Allow Documentation in other Stack Exchange communities](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/281689/allow-documentation-in-other-stack-exchange-communities) (Though it will be much closer to SO documentation than a plain old wiki, I'm sure.)

Comment: Yeah I understand the wiki. I was thinking too much out of the box I guess. Over analyzing like usual.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't think that's the point.

Documentation is intended* to fill a niche in the same way that Q&A did; there are users who wish to improve upon bad or incomplete documentation, and this gives them the opportunity to do so in a peer-reviewed, curated** fashion.

What you're suggesting is analogous to a forum.  Actually, what you'd *want* for that is a forum, or Slack channel, or something that *isn't* Stack Exchange-related, since the network isn't designed or engineered to support questions/discussions of that caliber.

<sup>*:  That's what I was told...</sup>

<sup>**: ...but the Java documentation (specifically the Java Arrays documentation) sticks out like a weed in a flower patch (personal opinion...</sup>

Comment: TIL there was/is an intention behind Documentation.